# Что делают с шашлыком?

Tags: выбор-слов

Шашлык - жарят?
Жаркой вообще-то называется процесс приготовления.
Пекут? Запекают? - последнее, похоже, правильно, но не употребляется.

Answer (score 1):

В словаре Ефремовой можно найти очень интересную информацию по этому поводу:

*шашлык*
1. **Способ приготовления** на разного рода жарящих и запекающих устройствах, на "живом огне", на углях мяса (кусочков баранины, говядины, свинины) , а также рыбы, креветок и т.п., нанизанных на вертел вместе с овощами и иной приправой.
2. Кушанье, приготовленное таким способом.

Если это способ приготовления, то получается, что шашлык "шашлычат".

В другом словаре (Кузнецов) можно найти сам ответ на вопрос:
Кушание из кусочков баранины (реже говядины, свинины), **зажаренной над огнём** на вертеле, шампуре.